# show that $p$ factors over $K$ into product of irreducible polynomials of the same degree.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a normal extention of $F$, let $p(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible. If $p(x)$ is not irreducible in $K[x]$, show that $p$ factors over $K$ into product of irreducible polynomials of the same degree.

If not suppose $\exists g_1, g_2 \in K[x]$ s.t $deg(g_1) \neq deg(g_2)$ then $K[x]/<g_1>$ and $K[x]/<g_2>$ are are extensions of different dimensions over $K$. Now construct $K(a_1,....,a_n)$ where $a_i$ are roots of $p(x)$. $K(a_1,....,a_n)$ is also a normal extension of $F$. Now can we show any contradiction?

Comment: Does this not follow from [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1434108/11619)? You may need to do a bit of gymnastics handling non-separable cases.

Comment: Yeah it follows from my last question. Because $\sigma(g_1)=g_2$. So they can't be of different degree as $\sigma$ is an automorphism. Later I got it. Sorry It didn't click when I was posting the problem.